# how to play a video, make it pause and then repeat with jQuery

Tags: jquery, video

I have a 3.5 second video that I want to auto play after the page loads, then pause and wait 5 seconds before repeating at that interval over and over. I have figured out how to make it pause, but that's as far as I've got. I've tried to piece together code from other topics here but I can't make it work. Here is my code:

```
var video = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];

video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(){
if(this.currentTime >= 3) {
this.pause();
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an interval to play the video from start every 8.5seconds?

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
//var video = $('#video')[0]; //jQuery selector for id video, if you prefer instead of above variable definition. 
video.oncanplay = function() {

   video.play();

   setInterval(function(){
     video.currentTime = 0; 
     video.play();
   },8500);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for responding but what happens is it just plays the video once and does not repeat.

Comment: The interval is supposed to replay the video from the beginning every 8.5 seconds.

Comment: Note that I am using the id selector. It is looking for an element with id="video". If you prefer using the name attribute you could change the video variable to `$('[name="video"]')[0`] instead. Just tried the code, it works. If it helps you, please mark it as the correct answer so that it can help others with the same or a similar problem in future.

Comment: I tried this on my site and it didn't work but I suspect that the wordpress theme I'm using has something blocking it from happening. I read in their KB that other people could not make similar scripts work either. Thanks for the help. I'm just going to increase the length of the video with a freeze frame to 8.5 seconds and set to autoplay.